# Java can't get relative path for file

Tags: java

[Image Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhKVm.png)Trying to access a test.txt file that is in the same location as my HelloController.java file but for some reason, it is showing that the file does not exist. I've tried moving the file around but it does not work.

Using the absolute path works, but this is a shared project so it will be ran on other computers. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to add it to the class path and [reading it as a class path resource](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/io/read-file-from-classpath/).

Answer (score 0):

The relative path root is your "working directory". Which means if you try to access "." you will start at your working directory. This directory is only set once for your application and is normally the folder which was opened when you started it.
When working with IDEs (like in your case) the working directory will be the root folder of your project (So the folder in which the pom.xml and src folders are located.
If you want to access the file via the normal file API you are currently using, just put the file in that diretory and it should work (given you share it with the other people in the same location).
If you need the file to be inside your generated output jar-file, you will need to use the File as a resource (See duffymo's answer), as the file does not exist by itself on the file system, but as a file inside your jar-file.
If you want to know your current working directory, you can create a File refrence to "." and expand it to an absolute path (Which will replace refrences like "." and ".." and generate a file path from your root) and then write it to the console. This would look something like this:

```java
// Get refrence to the current working directory
File workingDirectoryReference = new File(".");
// Convert it to an absolute path string
String absolutePath = workingDirectoryReference.getAbsolutePath();
// Output to console
System.out.println(absolutePath );
```